# Can then be called if the first callback does not return a Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm going through [Chain-ability of Promises](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html) and the code looks like this:

```
Promise.resolve(123)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res); // 123
        return 456;
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res); // 456
        return Promise.resolve(123); // Notice that we are returning a 
Promise
    })
```

The first callback does not return a promise, but the rest do.  Can `then` be called after the statement `.then((res) => { console.log(res);return 456;})` completes?

Comment: `.then` **always** returns a promise - what you return inside the callback is "promisified" if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@jaromanda-x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) mentioned,

**The then method returns a Promise which allows for method chaining.**

> You can pass a lambda to then and if it returns a promise, an
>   equivalent Promise will be exposed to the subsequent then in the
>   method chain. The below snippet simulates asynchronous code with the
>   setTimout function.

When a value is simply returned from within a then lambda, it will effectively return `Promise.resolve(<value returned by whichever handler was called>)`.

**Example**

```
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(1);
});

p2.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // 1
  return value + 1;
}).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value + '- This synchronous usage is virtually pointless'); // 2- This synchronous usage is virtually pointless
});

p2.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // 1
});
```

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)